# Contribution tokens

Tags: contributions

I am working on a new template for thank you letters and I can't find the contribution tokens that I used in the past. Unfortunately I deleted the old templates, so I don't remember what they were exactly. Now I only see tokens that relate to the contact and not the contribution itself, e.g. latest contribution.

Did those tokens disappear? What am I missing?

Comment: {contribution.total_amount} is the token, which I no longer see as an option from the dropdown. Maybe it's just me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be an issue with where you are trying to create your email template. If you do this via Find Contributions (eg then Action = Send Email) you should find that all your Contribution tokens are available for usage.